# Python: Is there a thread-safe version of a deque?

Tags: python, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, deque

I have a threaded program consisting of a `Consumer` class and a `Producer` class. Currently, I use a Fifo `queue.Queue` in the implementation, where the producer `put`s the data at the end of the queue and the consumer `get`s it.

However, I would like to add a feature where, if necessary, the `Consumer` can `put` back the (perhaps slightly modified) item that it `get`s by putting it back at the front of the `Queue` (so that the next item returned by `get` is the item just added, like in a stack).

I know this is possible with `deque`s, but I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554153/is-this-deque-thread-safe-in-python) that they are only thread-safe for `append()` and `popleft()`. For the purposes above I'll also need to use `appendleft()`.

Is there a thread-safe data structure that has the features of a `deque`? If not, could I make the `deque` thread-safe by putting in my own locks whenever I use `appendleft`?

Answer (score 8):

Deque author here.

- The operations you're interested in are all atomic.
- The only non-atomic operations are:  *remove()*, *index()*, *count*, and *clear()* due to equality tests which can make pure python callbacks or due to decrefs which can trigger arbitrary python code.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

While some `deque` features are not thread safe, what you're trying to do should be.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient **appends and pops from either side** of the deque